# Monitoring Kubernetes PVC disk usage

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor Kubernetes PVC disk usage. I need the memory that is in use for Persistent Volume Claim. I found the command:

> kubectl get --raw /api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims | jq

Return:

```
"status":{
            "phase":"Bound",
            "accessModes":[
               "ReadWriteOnce"
            ],
            "capacity":{
               "storage":"1Gi"
            }
         }
```

But it only brings me the full capacity of the disk, and as I said I need the used one

Does anyone know which command could return this information to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a definitive anwser, but I hope this will help you. Also, I would be interested if someone has a better anwser.

### Get current usage

> The PersistentVolume subsystem provides an API for users and administrators that abstracts details of how storage is provided from how it is consumed.
>
> -- [Persistent Volume | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#introduction:%7E:text=The%20PersistentVolume%20subsystem%20provides%20an%20API,provided%20from%20how%20it%20is%20consumed.)

As stated in the Kubernetes documentation, PV (PersistentVolume) and PVC (PersistentVolumeClaim) are abstractions over storage. As such, I do not think you can inspect PV or PVC, but you can inspect the storage medium.

To get the usage, create a debugging pod which will use your PVC, from which you will check the usage. This should work depending on your storage provider.

```yaml
# volume-size-debugger.yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: volume-size-debugger
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: debug-pv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: <pvc-name>
  containers:
  - name: debugger
    image: busybox
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/data"
      name: debug-pv
```

Apply the above manifest with `kubectl apply -f volume-size-debugger.yaml`, and run a shell inside it with `kubectl exec -it volume-size-debugger sh`. Inside the shell run `du -sh` to get the usage in a human readable format.

### Monitoring

As I am sure you have noticed, this is not especially useful for monitoring. It may be useful for a one-time check from time to time, but not for monitoring or low disk space alerts.

One way to setup monitoring would be to have a similar sidecar pod like ours above and gather our metrics from there. One such example seems to be the [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter).

Another way would be to use [CSI](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/01/15/container-storage-interface-ga/) (Container Storage Interface). I have not used CSI and do not know enough about it to really explain more. But here are a couple of related issues and related Kubernetes documentation:

- [Monitoring Kubernetes PersistentVolumes - prometheus-operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2359)
- [Volume stats missing - csi-digitalocean](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean/issues/134)
- [Storage Capacity | Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-capacity/)

Answer (score 5):

+1 to [touchmarine's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14425365/touchmarine) answer however I'd like to expand it a bit and add also my three cents.

> But it only brings me the full capacity of the disk, and as I said I
> need the used one

`PVC` is an abstraction which represents **a request for a storage** and simply doesn't store such information as disk usage. As a higher level abstraction it doesn't care at all how the underlying storage is used by its consumer.

@touchmarine, Instead of using a `Pod` whose only function is to `sleep` and every time you need to check the disk usage you need to attach to it maually, I would propose to use something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: media
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: media
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: media
      - name: busybox
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do du -sh /data; sleep 10;done"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data"
          name: media
```

It can be of course a single-container `busybox` `Pod` as in @touchmarine's example but here I decided to to show also how it can be used as a sidecar running next to `nginx` container within a single `Pod`.

As it runs a simple bash script - an infinite while loop, which prints out current disk usage to the standard output it can be read with `kubectl logs` without a need of using `kubectl exec` and attaching to the `Pod`:

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-deployment-56bb5c87f6-dqs5h busybox
20.0K   /data
20.0K   /data
20.0K   /data
```

I guess it can be also used more effectively to configure some sort of monitoring of disk usage.

Comment: That is a simple and useful way, utilising the logs.

Comment: I'm new to kubernetes, I saw that you put a yaml. How would I run this script? Is it a command to collect information?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you share your `Deployment` or `Pod` definition. I guess your `PVC` is used by some `Pod`,so you can add to this definition second `busybox` container which only function is to mount the same volume and check its current usage. `command: ["/bin/sh"]` and `args: ["-c", "while true; do du -sh /data; sleep 10;done"]` are key lines here. `du -sh /data` is checking your disk usage every 10 seconds and prints it to the standard output so that it can be checked easily using `kubectl logs <pod_name> <container_name>`. You can apply it by `kubectl apply -f`